# How can i make open the door button and close the door button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button

**Example**
when the player is near the object
the button will appear on screen

when the player moves away from the object the button will be hidden.

How can i make that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a collider and a trigger to your door. You also have to add a collider to your player for them to interact.

Then you can implement something like this on your door GameObject:

```
public GameObject MyButton;

// this function gets called when your player enters a "trigger space"
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    MyButton.SetActive(true);
}

// this function gets called when your player exits a "trigger space"
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    MyButton.SetActive(false);
}
```

You can check this article to learn about how this all works: https://www.codinblack.com/colliders-and-triggers-in-unity3d/